# Can i provide services in Android app

Tags: android

My question may seem foolish to you! I just have a doubt that, what happens if i dev an android app, showing a text that

"Do you want an android app like this? Just contact me on abcd@gmail.com"

What does happen? Does google ban!

Thank you!

Comment: So you've developed an entire functional app, and somewhere in the app you offer your development service?  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Google will not ban, at least not immediately. If enough users report your app they might remove it from the market. If that happens repeatedly, your account might get banned.

Comment: thanks for ur replies..i actually dint build any app! I jus thought of this, but didn't understand what google does, that's why made a thread here..

Comment: I think he means thats the only thing the app does. Either way they still probably won't ban it unless people complain which they probably won't unless you misrepresent it in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are distributing your app on Market, check the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement.